# How to test that spawned Node child process is detached and unref()'ed?

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, child-process, spawn

I have a desktop Node.js application that spawns a child process. After spawning, all communications between the parent and child processes go through the network, and I need the processes to be completely independent of each other. `spawn()`'s [`option.detached`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#optionsdetached) allows for the child process to continue running after the parent exits, and [`subprocess.unref()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#subprocessunref) allows the parent to exit independently of the child.

While everything works and is pretty easy to manually test (track the processes in Task Manager/Activity Monitor and see what happens when one of the processes is killed/exits), I'm wondering about how I could test this programmatically, specifically using Jest.

There are two testing scenarios:

1. `option.detached` – test whether the child process lives even after the parent process exits. But how can I simulate a parent exiting if the parent process *is the process Jest tests run in*? Perhaps I could simulate/mock `process.exit()` somehow?
2. `unref()` – test whether the parent process can exit without waiting for the child process. Now this is even more difficult and I have no idea how to test this. Perhaps mock the child process with a sample long-lived process, like `setTimeout(fn, 999999)`? Then again, how do I test whether the parent process exits?

Comment: To test process independence, you will need two things.  An ability to see which processes are running in the operating system and an ability to kill or stop a process.  Then, run processes A and B.  Kill A and see if B is still running.  Run processes A and B.  Kill B and see if A is still running.  If you don't want to view this via an OS process list, then each process could start up a web server on a known port and you could send a request to each web server to see who responds (e.g. who is still operating).

Comment: You could even use that web server to accept an "exit" command to tell the process to call `process.exit()` on itself to "kill" itself as your means of killing or stopping a process.  Then, send your http request to each web server and see which ones respond.